# Marionette.Application() has no Method initRegionManager

Tags: requirejs, marionette

im struggling with a weird Issue with Backbone.Marionette an requireJS.

RquireJS is configured like https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/wiki/Using-marionette-with-requirejs says:

```
require.config({

deps: ['main'],

paths : {
    backbone : '../vendor/backbone.marionette/backbone',
    underscore : '../vendor/underscore/underscore',
    jquery : '../vendor/jquery/jquery',
    marionette : '../vendor/backbone.marionette/backbone.marionette.min'
},
shim : {
    jquery : {
        exports : 'jQuery'
    },
    underscore : {
        exports : '_'
    },
    backbone : {
        deps : ['jquery', 'underscore'],
        exports : 'Backbone'
    },
    marionette : {
        deps : ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone'],
        exports : 'Marionette'
    }
}
});
```

The main.js:

```
require([
    'app'
],
function(App) {
    App.start();
}
);
```

And the app.js:

```
define([
    'marionette'
],
function(Marionette) {
    var app = Marionette.Application();
    return app;
}
);
```

But when I wanna start a Application my Console says:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method '_initRegionManager'
```

I did nothing special so far:

```
define(
[
    'marionette'
],
function(Marionette) {
    "use strict";

    var app = Marionette.Application();

    // app.on('initialize:after', function() {
    //  console.log("Initialize:After");
    // });
    return app;
}
);
```

And in the main.js (Startingpoint) i require the code above and wanna start it.
But it fails at Marionette.Application();

When i look into the marionette.js i can clearly see underscore extending the Application with the _initRegionManager-Method. Also in the Prototype-list of the Marionette-Object i can see the method.

Any ideas what i'm missing here?

Comment: can you also paste your require config?

Comment: Edited all js files i use currently

Comment: I dont see anything wrong, the only line that I dont understand is this... deps: ['main'], why do you have it there, in the code sample of the tutorial is not there.

Comment: ok now that I understand that line, i think the error could be the versions you are using, If you are using the AMD version of Marionette then you should not need to shim marionette.

Comment: Tried it both ways. With the AMD Version, including also Backbone.wreqr and so on. Exactly the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your require.config ({ … })  should be in main.js and also as Ratweb_on indicated, there should not be “deps: [‘main’]” in the require.config.
You can follow this [example in here](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette), and ignore the jquerymobile stuffs. Essentially it dose the initialization in the same way as your code intended.
See [main.js](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette/blob/master/js/main.js) and [app.js](https://github.com/mingchan/jquerymobile-marionette/blob/master/js/main.js).

**Updated**

In your app.js

```
var app = Marionette.Application();
```

Should be

```
var app = new Marionette.Application();
```

Comment: With deps:['main'] just starts the app within another file then the configuration. I can also do it the way in ur link. But i doesn't change the error.
Id built it after this example: https://github.com/jameslai/backbone-marionette-boilerplate/tree/master/js

Comment: Can you post your code in github and I can to fork it and repro the issue and see what is wrong.

Comment: Updated with what you need to fix

Comment: ridiculous...
If you dont blindly copy and paste, you may miss a important keyword.
Thanks a lot!